# Jquery dialog isn't working in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Now I know it's been asked before but I can't seem to get JQUERY dialog to work.

I have an easy example that I got from the JQUERY website but the dialog never pops up.

My _Layout.cshtml page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
            <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <section id="login">
                            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                        </section>
                        <nav>
                            <ul id="menu">
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="body">
                @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>

            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        </body>
    </html>
```

My Index.cshtml page

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("HELLO");
    });
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
        });
    </script>
```

The alert pops up but the dialog doesn't, any idea why?

EDIT: Did some editing and now I have this.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("HELLO");
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("HELLO2");
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert("HELLO3");
    });
</script>
```

Now when I have three alerts, it will alert HELLO and HELLO2 but it never does HELLO3.. however if I put the HELLO3 script above the dialog script it will display all 3 alerts. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It works just find by itself: http://jsfiddle.net/Dy2Xw/

Check your scripts to make sure they are loading properly. Also, it appears you are loading the jquery base js twice.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js "></script>
```

You also have two css files - not sure why you would need both of those:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Clean up those script loads, check the console for any js errors, put in only what you need and try it again.

Comment: Cleaned it up and I see that it works with JSFIDDLE but I can't get my mind around why it won't work in my application. I'm pretty sure the scripts are loading correct because if they weren't then the HELLO alert wouldn't work.

Comment: No errors BTW, but If you see my edited version it doesn't seem to reach alert #3 if I put the dialog script between alert #2 and #3. Any ideas?

Comment: @Claud25 The `alert` is basic js wrapped in a jquery `ready` function. It doesn't need jquery ui to work unlike the `dialog`. Check that the scripts are loading properly and remove any unnecessary scripts. In your code example you have two different versions of jquery loading and two different versions of jquery ui loading. Clean these up. You don't need two of each. Clean up the css as well.

Comment: How can I exactly check if they are loading properly? Because I'm about to give up. Right now I only have two scripts included like it shows in my edited version. Any suggestion on what I should have in my head because at this point I'm about to just forget about it.

Comment: @Claud25 Try just straight link to the CDN's `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`. For the css, which is needed for the dialog, use this in the `link` tag: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`. That should remove any load errors that you can figure out later.

Comment: Yah it still doesn't work, I must be doing something wrong. I appreciate the help but I'll try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with location of js files before the `</body>` vs `<head>` tag. Move `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` to `<head></head>` tag